# function not returning variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a function that takes a parameter(key) to retrieve it's value from a cookie. I call that function anywhere that I need a specific bit of information. except everything comes back as Undefined.

```
//before $(document).ready();
var keyval = ""; //VARIABLE FOR PASSING COOKIE VALUE
var getCookieVal =function(c_name){
var cleanCookie = document.cookie.substr(0, document.cookie.indexOf("; __utma="));//REMOVES EXTRA INFORMATION
var cookieArr = cleanCookie.split(";");//MAKES AN ARRAY OF EACH PAIR
    $.each(cookieArr, function(index, val){
        var valArr = val.split("=");//SPLITS THE KEY VALUE PAIR INTO AN ARRAY
        var key = valArr[0];
        keyval = valArr[1];
        if (key == c_name){
            alert(keyval);//ALERTS CORRECT ANSWER
            return keyval;
        }
    });
    console.log(keyval);//RETURNS UNDEFINED
}

//IN ANOTHER FILE I CALL THE FUNCTION:
$(document).ready(function(){
    getCookieVal("username");
    alert(keyval);//RETURNS UNDEFINED
});
```

Anyone know what I did wrong or how I can get that value?

Comment: Your code is improperly indented which makes it harder to read. Please correct that.

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack overflow. Still figuring out the code area. although I have been told to put my first bracket on the next line. Old habits i guess.

Comment: You can copy your JavaScript code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and then click on the "TidyUp" button to properly format the code. Then just copy-paste the resulting code back into your question, select it and click on the "Code Sample" icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var getCookieVal = function(key) {
    var coo = document.cookie;
        arr = coo.substr(0, coo.indexOf('; __utma=')).split(';'),
        value;
    $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
        var valArr = v.split('=');
        if ( valArr[0] === key ) {
            value = vallArr[1];
            return false;
        }            
    });
    return value;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var keyval = getCookieVal('username');
    alert(keyval);
});
```

So you `return false` inside the if-branch (once you find the desired value) to break out of the `$.each` loop. Then, you just `return value` from the `getCookieVal` function.

Note that there is **no need** to define a global `keyval` variable here.

Comment: That Was it! I was working on that for a few hours yesterday. Never thought about breaking out of the loop. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
return keyval;
```

...returns from the anonymous function you passed to `$.each`, not from your `getCookieVal` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` to break out of your loop.  Otherwise, the loop continues and `keyval` is overwritten.  You are returning `keyval`, which will not break the loop.  Change that to `false` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be reduced to this (assuming that caller of getCookieVal is trusted)

```
function getCookieVal(name)
{
    var pattern = new RegExp('(?:^|;)' + name + '=([^;]*)', 'i'),
         matches = pattern.exec(document.cookie);
    return matches ? matches[1] : null;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var keyval = getCookieVal('username');
    alert(keyval);
});
```